# Python3 Removing Non-Printable chars from text

Tags: string, python-3.x, utf-8, io, encode

I have an inputfile and reading lines, making some operations and put them into outputfile.

When I open output file in notepad, there is no problem.
When I open output file in notepad++ (in UTF8 encoding format or ANSI), there are some non-printable chars. E.g. SOH(Start of Heading)

How can I remove non-printable chars?

The bytecode of SOH is 01. Is there a method like `string.remove(0x01)` ??

Comment: They're still in your Notepad file, it just doesn't print the non-printable characters :P

Comment: Are the unprintable characters also in the input file? If not you might actually want to fix your script so it doesn't generate those unnecessary characters in the first place.

Comment: yes unprintable chars also exist in input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your text by calling the `str.isprintable()` method on each character. You may need to be careful though, since some characters you may want to preserve (such as tabs and newlines) are considered unprintable.

Here's some quick (untested) code:

```
for line in input_file:
    # do your processing to the line here

    line = "".join(c for c in line if c.isprintable() or c in "\n\t")  # filter line
    output_file.write(line)
```

You could probably also do the filtering before your other processing if you wanted to.